# lightning-record-edit-form not showing personal account fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, person-accounts

I have gone through all the steps described in the documentation, but I don't understand why the personal account custom fields are not visible.

Needless to say that the custom fields (__pc) exist and work perfectly in other processes (apex, UI etc etc).

```
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsubmit ={handleAccountSubmit}>

            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='FirstName'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='LastName'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='PersonEmail'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            field-name='PrefijoTelef__pc'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='Phone'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='CanalDeEntrada__pc'
                            value={leadSourceDefaultValue}>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='DetalleDelCanalDeEntrada__pc'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='ComoNosHaConocido__pc'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='PersonBirthdate'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field
                            variant="label-stacked"
                            field-name='Genero__pc'>
                    </lightning-input-field>
                </div>

            </div>
            <lightning-button data-id="submit-account-btn" type="submit" class="slds-hidden"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

With this output where only std person account fields are shown:

[image]

Comment: All your custom fields are Contact fields. If you do `object-api-name="Contact"`, replace the "__pc" by "__c" and provide a Contact ID, do you see the fields? Have you tried a custom Account field (with "__c")? (You don't use `import ... @salesforce/schema/Account..._pc` originally, do you? These imports do not seem to work for Personal Accounts on the Account object.)

Comment: Have you checked the Working with Person Accounts section in the [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) documentation?

Comment: Make sure that the field you are using in the lightning-record-edit-form is available on the page layout of the person account record type.

Comment: Person Accounts typically require a specific record type ,so I would make sure that is included in the form definition

Comment: __pc -> Custom Persona Account Field, source: https://www.apexhours.com/suffixes-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 0):

All the fields that aren't showing are custom, so have you set the view/edit permission for each one?

The fields will inherit the access configuration to display on the screen